# Why is this sentence like this なんと ～であることか and not like なんと ～でしょう?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

> **なんと**醜い私の声**であることか。**

I wanted to know the difference. Is it the nuance?

Could someone explain it to me?

Thanks in advance! :]

Comment: There is another one? Could you tell me where it is?

Answer (score 2):

Simply なんと～(こと)でしょう is politer because でしょう is the polite form of だろう. It would be used when the speaker is talking politely, i.e., using ～です/～ます. Folk tales for children are usually narrated in this tone.

なんと～(こと)だろう is the non-polite equivalent, which is typically found in modern novels targeted at adults.

なんと～(こと)か is roughly the same as なんと～(こと)だろう, but it sounds a bit more literary and stiff. I don't think it's archaic. [More examples here](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=kotoka).

Answer (score 0):

Neither is used in real life.  Only in stories, anime, theatre, etc.

なんと醜い声であることか --  may be for an older reader.  19C classic for teenagers or adults.  Heike or Konjaku translated into modern Jp.

なんと醜い声でしょう -- may be for a younger reader. Under 10. [Snow White]

The former sounds more male.  More formal.

今遠い幸せな日々を思い出すのは、何と辛いことだろう。

これはなんて美しい花なんでしょう！」 --- This sounds more like translated from a Western language. Grimm's tales, Le Petit Prince, etc.

Answer (score -1):

ことか is used to express strong surprise.
http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=kotoka

でしょう is the polite form of だろう and is used to express probability.
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/46845/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86/

なんと醜い私の声であることか。
How terrrible my voice is!

なんと醜い私の声でしょう。
My voice seems terrible, doesn't it?